# How can I get array of workers ? Can't find my mistake i am newbee

Tags: php, arrays, json

Can't decode JSON to foreach 
 Need help

```
<?php 

$workers      = 'https://api.ethermine.org/miner/***/workers';
$workersContent = file_get_contents($workers);
$workersJson = json_decode($workersContent, true);
foreach ($workersJson['data']['worker'] as $worker) {
    $output = $worker['worker'][1]; 

     echo $output;
 }


?>
```

How can I get array of workers ? Can't find my mistake i am newbee ☺

Comment: Add the JSON you get from the API. (Or at least a small part of it, that shows the structure)

Comment: can you please post what is value of `$workersJson`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
$workers        = 'https://api.ethermine.org/miner/YOURAPIKEY/workers';
$workersContent = file_get_contents($workers);
$workersJson    = json_decode($workersContent, true);

foreach ($workersJson['data'] as $worker) {

    //$worker["worker"] <-- accessing gtx1050tix4
    //$worker["time"] <-- accessing 1520599200
    //etc

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $worker );
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [worker] => gtx1050tix4
    [time] => 1520599200
    [lastSeen] => 1520599074
    [reportedHashrate] => 45518082
    [currentHashrate] => 43333333.333333
    [validShares] => 39
    [invalidShares] => 0
    [staleShares] => 0
    [averageHashrate] => 43559413.580247
)
```

Comment: You might wanna rename the api key to something like `YOURAPIKEY`

Comment: Bear in mind there's a change history, so people can see the value you removed. I'm not familiar with the site in question, but if it's important that value is secret you might want to "renew" your key.

Answer (score 1):

PLease try this:

```
<?php 
$workers      = 'https://api.ethermine.org/miner/YOURAPIKEY/workers';
$workersContent = file_get_contents($workers);
$workersJson = json_decode($workersContent, true);
//print_r($workersJson);
foreach ($workersJson['data'] as $worker) {
    $output = $worker['worker']; 
     echo $output;
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

When visiting the url, I can see the structure is this :

```
{"status":"OK","data":[{"worker":"gtx1050tix4","time":1520599200,"lastSeen":1520599074,"reportedHashrate":45518082,"currentHashrate":43333333.333333336,"validShares":39,"invalidShares":0,"staleShares":0,"averageHashrate":43559413.580246896}]}
```

If you want to get `gtx1050tix4` then the answer is

```
foreach ($workersJson['data']['worker'] as $worker) {
    $output = $worker; 

    echo $output;
```

}

And if you want to get the whole data and output from there, the answer is

```
    foreach ($workersJson['data'] as $data) {
        $worker = $data['worker'];
        $time = $data['time']; // any key from json


       echo $worker;
```

}

Hopefully this clears stuff up for you